# setting maximum row in nsruleeditor

Tags: cocoa

I am using NSRuleEditor for displaying some predicate operations. 
I can add new row by clicking the "+" button and delete a row when "-" button is clicked. 
My requirement is setting maximum number of permissible row to be added to the NSRuleEditor and then disable "+" button when number of rows reached that criteria and vice versa.

Any please let me know how can I disable "+" button when maximum row condition is reached?

Regards,
iSight